# Classification tree in R program

Tags: r

I don't know why I cannot plot a tree using the following code.

```
m3<-rpart(X~ .,data=data1r[1:5000,],method = "class",model = TRUE)
```

By the way, the data I use is only integer 0 and 1, will it affect the final result?

Comment: there is no code for plotting there; have a read of the docs around `plot`

Comment: `rpart()` only constructs the three, doesn't plot it. See `plot`. Show us your `plot` code if it doesn't work.

Comment: Also for plotting trees from rpart/random-forests, see these questions on over on CrossValidated [Best way to present a random forest in a publication?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2344/best-way-to-present-a-random-forest-in-a-publication), [How to actually plot a sample tree from randomForest::getTree()?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41443/how-to-actually-plot-a-sample-tree-from-randomforestgettree)

Comment: i use the following code but only one leaf node is presented.
rpart.plot(m3)